# Margin-bottom adding to top

Tags: html, css

I want to create a space above and below my header div, and so I gave it a margin-top and margin-bottom. The margin-bottom isn't adding a space on the bottom though. Instead, it's adding the margin-bottom to the top, and the content below is right against it.

This is literally all the code i have so far in my body:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img class="logo" src="Images/logo.png"/>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="Twitter">
                <a href="http://twitter.com/AccountLink">
                    <img src="Images/twitter.png"/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="banner"><img src="Images/banner.jpg"/></div>
</body>
```

And my css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.header .logo {
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.header .navigation {

    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Which element are you referring to? You're setting the `margin-top` explicitly on the `header`, that's why it's there. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: What do you want? Adding margin only on the bottom of header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.header {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Compatibility table for browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You have floated navigation, yet your header does not have specified height. Use some element to clear after your navigation or apply overflow: hidden; to your header.
For example:

```
.header {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try using padding instead of margin

    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;

also add 
.banner{  padding-top:10px;}

or adjust to your needs
```